# How to create one static library from several others static libraries in C on Linux?

Tags: linker, static-linking, unix-ar

For example,
we have three following libraries:

> 1.1.......................lib_A.a
>
> 1.2.......................lib_B.a
>
> 1.3.......................lib_C.a

Now I want to create one library which consists of all the above static libraries.

I have used following command:

```
ar -crs lib_Z.a lib_A.a lib_B.a lib_C.a
```

When I create final executable with `lib_Z.a`, the compiler gives me the following error:

> error adding symbols: archive has no index; run ranlib to add one

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Your `lib_Z.a` contains no object files; it only contains other `.a` files, and the loader doesn't know how to handle that.  Running `ranlib` wouldn't help; it wouldn't find any object files in the `lib_Z.a` archive.  You have to extract the object files from the separate libraries and then build them all into the result:

```
mkdir Work
cd Work
ar -x ../lib_A.a
ar -x ../lib_B.a
ar -x ../lib_C.a
ar -crs ../lib_Z.a *.o
cd ..
rm -fr Work
```

The only trouble you can run into is if two of the libraries contain the same object file name (e.g. `lib_A.a` contains `config.o` and so does `lib_B.a` but they define different configurations).  You would have to rename one (or both) of the object files:

```
…
ar -x ../lib_A.a
mv config.o A_config.o
ar -x ../lib_B.a
mv config.o B_config.o
…
```