# Create one static library from several others static libraries in Makefile

Tags: makefile, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I got the same issue than [How to create one static library from several others static libraries in C on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527337/how-to-create-one-static-library-from-several-others-static-libraries-in-c-on-li)

The answer worked for me when I did manually, but how to automatize this with a Makefile ? My current rule is:

```
$(STATIC_LIB_TARGET): $(LIB_OBJS) $(THIRDPART_LIBS)
    $(Q)cd $(BUILD) && $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIB_OBJS) && ranlib $@
```

`$(STATIC_LIB_TARGET)` is my static lib I want to create, `$(LIB_OBJS)` contains my project `.o` files inside my output folder `$(BUILD)` and `$(THIRDPART_LIBS)` contains the list of external `.a` that I have to `ar -x`. My issue is that `ar -x` shall be called for each static lib and cannot be grouped and the list of extracted .o files shall be got into Makefile variable.

I could use `foreach` over `$(THIRDPART_LIBS)` or call shell script, but this seems complicated. I think a more elegant solution exists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since I did not have an answer. I've finally done by calling external bash script. Ugly but seems working for me. Hope to have a proper way of doing it.

Makefile:

```
$(STATIC_LIB_TARGET): $(LIB_OBJS) ...
ifneq ($(THIRDPART_LIBS),)
    ./$(M)/alib.sh $(BUILD) $(THIRDPART_LIBS)
    cd $(BUILD) && $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIB_OBJS) $(THIRDPART_OBJS) _lib*/*.o && ranlib $@
else
    cd $(BUILD) && $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIB_OBJS) $(THIRDPART_OBJS) && ranlib $@
endif
```

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
BUILD=$1
shift

for LIB in $*;
do
   FOLDER=$BUILD/_`basename $LIB .a`
   rm -fr $FOLDER 2> /dev/null
   mkdir -p $FOLDER
   (cd $FOLDER; ar -x $LIB)
done
```